# Error:(15, 0)Gradle DSL method not found 'runProguard()';

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-build

I'm having trouble in here. I'm trying to make the code run from this https://github.com/TaurusXi/GuideBackgroundColorAnimation and as I open and build the project I'm having this kind of error. I'm new on android development and I don't know a lot.

I've already done changing the `runProguard` to `minifyEnabled` here my code

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

**My compile sdk version is API 22: Android 5.1**

**Build tools Version : 22.0.1**

Comment: If you want to disable proguard (as you have set `minifyEnabled` to false) then you can simply delete the complete `release` block.

Comment: Honestly I don't know for what is that block for its just I download the zip file try to run and test and got that kind of error. Can I know what is proguard? I will try what you said and give feed back later. T

Comment: Proguard is a tool to minify your app's size (simply said). Could be usefull on a large project. But that's off-topic. Have you already clicked 'Gradle Sync'?

Comment: Ow. Thanks for answering though its a off-topic question. Yes I already solved my problem. Its just I don't know there is another proGuard that declared from other Gradle so i change it also to minifyEnabled.